# Como deixar os 4 primeiros caracteres de uma string menores que os demais

Tags: php, css

Fiz uma pesquisa e não encontrei um código para deixar apenas os 4 primeiros caracteres de uma string com um tamanho menor.

Tentei este código:

```
$str = "Códigos"; 
$str = strtolower($str);
```

Só que eu preciso deixar são os 4 primeiros números menores que os demais. O que sempre encontro são referentes a *strings*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acho que pode resolver assim:

```
$numero = '1234567890';
echo '<small>'.substr($numero, 0, 4).'</small>'.substr($numero, 5);
```

Usando `substr` separei a string em 2 partes, uma com os 4 primeiros numeros `.substr(0, 4)` e outra com o restante `.substr(5)` e adicionei a tag `<small>` para mostrar em uma fonte menor.

O resultado será algo assim no browser:

```
<small>1234</small>567890
```

Comment: Oxe, uma negativada com menos de 8 seg.

Comment: Dei -1 pois apesar de ser uma tentativa de ajudar, você não levou em consideração que o AP pode não entender que linguagem é essa. E a tag da pergunta é PHP.

Comment: Dei -1 pois além de a resposta não estar de acordo com a pergunta, a pergunta ainda está fraca, imatura e não deveria ser recompensada.

Comment: Poxa @DiegoFelipe , não é pq não sei o endereço exato que eu não posso apontar a direção certa. Eu deixei claro na resposta que não sei PHP, mas o caminho é aquele mesmo.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu, ok, não precisa me positivar/recompensar. Mas não precisava negativar, pois o caminho é aquele mesmo.

Comment: Não me leve a mal, mas se eu tenho uma dúvida em java e você me dá um exemplo em C# pq são parecidas, não é a mesma coisa que mostrar uma direção. Adicione uma pequena explicação do que o código faz, pois alem de mostrar em outra linguagem, você nem explicou como o código funciona. A intenção do -1 é fazer com que a resposta seja melhorada apenas, não uma tentativa de retaliar sua resposta.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe, justo. Editei a resposta. Realmente eu podia entregar uma resposta melhor.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu, editei a resposta. Pode validar, por gentileza?

Comment: @DanielOmine, editei a resposta e sumiu sua edição. Mas obrigado pela contribuição com PHP.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi como eu disse, a questão não é apenas a falta de qualidade na sua resposta, mas também a falta de qualidade da pergunta. Eu acho que perguntas como essa não devem ser incentivadas. Comentei com o autor sobre as falhas das perguntas e até agora o mesmo não publicou código de tentativa, erros, nada. Leitura sugerida: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308358/1014588

Answer (score 2):

Em php você pode fazer um `substr()` para pegar as 4 primeiras posições e depois usar o `<font>` para coloca-la menor .

**Exemplo:**

```
$str = "Gabriel Rodrigues";

function examplo($str) {
   return "<font size='1'>" . substr($str, 0, 4) . "</font>" . substr($str, 5);
}

echo examplo($str);
```